# Cursor jumps 1 or 2 columns to the right after line up / down ( j / k )

Tags: cursor

Somehow my cursor jumps to the right in some filetypes (html, vue, json, maybe others...) when I switch lines with j or k

[image: Jumpy cursor...]

My .vimrc is kinda messy atm...but I've seen worse... :)

```
" Basics {{{
syntax on

let mapleader = ","

set shell=/bin/bash
set nocompatible
set t_Co=256
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set encoding=utf-8
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set hidden
set laststatus=2
set relativenumber
set number
set switchbuf=usetab,newtab
set helplang=de
set ffs=unix,dos
set autoindent
set ttyfast
set wildmenu
set noshowmode
set showcmd
set cmdheight=1
set updatetime=100
set modeline
set modelines=1
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=0
set foldnestmax=1
set foldminlines=100
set conceallevel=0
set concealcursor=
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set noexpandtab
" }}}
" Mappings {{{
"========================= [MAPPINGS] =========================

map <silent> <F2> :call fzf#run({'source': 'rg --files --column --no-heading --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*"', 'sink': 'e', 'down': '~30%'})<cr>
let g:fzf_colors =
\ {
\ 'fg': ['fg', 'Normal'],
\ 'bg': ['bg', 'Normal']
\}
map <silent> <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
no <Leader>ws :ToggleWorkspace<cr>
no <Leader>bw :bwipeout<cr>
no <Space> za
no <Leader>we <C-W>=
ino <C-e> <C-o>$
ino <C-q> <C-o>0
" ino kj <Esc>
" ino jk <Esc>
" }}}

" Plugins {{{
" Vundle Setup {{{
set runtimepath=$HOME/vimfiles,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,$HOME/.vim/bundle/,$HOME/.vim/
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
" }}}
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
Plugin 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'

Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
colorscheme donbass
set background=light

Plugin 'benmills/vimux'
Plugin 'jtdowney/vimux-cargo'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary.git'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround.git'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs.git'

Plugin 'thaerkh/vim-workspace'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-obsession'

Plugin 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
Plugin 'racer-rust/vim-racer'

Plugin 'w0rp/ale'

Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'

Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}

Plugin 'ap/vim-css-color'

Plugin 'junegunn/fzf'

"============================================================

Plugin 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
let g:markdown_folding=1

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" ==================== [YouCompleteMe] =====================
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
" ==================== [Airline] =========================
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
let g:airline_theme = 'solarized'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'

let g:airline#enable#fugitive = 1
let g:airline#enable#bufferline = 1
let g:airline#enable#syntastic = 1

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_idx_mode = 1
nmap <leader>1 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab1
nmap <leader>2 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab2
nmap <leader>3 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab3
nmap <leader>4 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab4
nmap <leader>5 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab5
nmap <leader>6 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab6
nmap <leader>7 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab7
nmap <leader>8 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab8
nmap <leader>9 <Plug>AirlineSelectTab9
nmap <leader>n <Plug>AirlineSelectPrevTab
nmap <leader>m <Plug>AirlineSelectNextTab

Plugin 'jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator'
"================== [vim-vue] ===================
Plugin 'posva/vim-vue'
let g:vue_disable_pre_processor = 0

"================== [GitGutter] =================
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
let g:gitgutter_grep='grep'

"================== [UltiSnips] =================
" Track the engine.
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use
" https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<s-tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"

"================== [Syntastic] =================
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'

" }}}
" AutoCMDs {{{
" ========================================================
" ===== AUTOCMDs
" ========================================================
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,php,vimrc,vue,javascript,js  autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %s/\s\+$//e
autocmd FileType vue setl sw=2 sts=2 ts=2  expandtab
autocmd FileType javascript,js setl sw=2 sts=2 ts=2 noexpandtab
autocmd FileType json set sw=2 sts=2 ts=2 noexpandtab
autocmd FileType md setl sw=2 sts=2 ts=2 noexpandtab
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.vue setf vue
" }}}
```

Really hoping for a solution, I guess it's a plugin but I've disabled most of them one by one, still the same "error".... So I'm out of ideas really.

Comment: Do you notice a delay between when you press J or K and when the cursor actually moves? If so, a mapping is definitely in play. Do you notice anything out of the ordinary with `:map j` or `:map k`? What about in the bottom right of the screen when you press a key (see `:h showcmd`)?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed the delay, that's why I've disabled the jk, kj <Esc> mappings, I thought there was a "hidden" space behind the <Esc> somewhere, didn't help tho. There's nothing showing up in the showcmd area when pressing j or k. I suspect a weird glitch in one of the plugins still.... Although I dis- and re-enabled all plugins I've recently installed... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ruled out tmux....vim behaves the same in a simple terminal... :/

Comment: Can you check the output of map as mentioned above? Does this persist with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: Sorry @ZeroKnight I misunderstood what exactly you wanted. So @d-ben-knoble `:map k` and `:map j` return no mapping `vim -u NONE`, so with vanilla settings, everything works as it should. I guess it's a misbehaving plugin. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so *in my case* disabling `thaerkh/vim-workspace` solved the issue. If it's the fault of the plugin or a combination of plugins and settings, I don't know. I might investigate that further at a later point and post my findings here. I really love that plugin, it's like vim-obsession, but fully automated...so yeah...disabling it is somewhat annoying. :/

Also: https://github.com/thaerkh/vim-workspace/issues/9 (>_<)